# Woocommerce Tax_query with LIKE terms

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to query all the products by "color" attribute. But some of my product's color attribute is set like this "01 blue", "02 blue", "01 black" and so on. What I want to do is to load products by color that is likely the given color. Sample color is blue, so it will get all products with 01 blue, 02 blue color attribute.

I have these codes but it is not working:

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'posts_per_page' => 12,
              'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'pa_product-color',
                      'field' => 'slug',
                      'terms' => 'featured-product',
                      'compare' => 'LIKE'
                  )
              )
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_product-color',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

This should get you the products with the color blue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, tax_query don't have `LIKE` operator. Possible values are `IN`, `NOT IN`, `AND`, `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`. Default value is `IN`.

You should write custom SQL Query

Look: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters